# How do I pass $in_foooter to wp_enqueue_script() without passing other params?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts, parameter

I have some scripts that I'm enqueueing like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
wp_enqueue_script("myscript" , get_template_directory_uri()."/js/myscript.js", Array('myscript'), " ");
```

I want to enqueue them in the footer, which means I should use the last parameter of [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Parameters), but I don't always want to pass the other params.

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer);
```

How do I get to `$in_footer` without messing up the default params in between it and `$handle`? Can I just put empty strings for each?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `array()` for `$deps`, and `NULL` for `$ver`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, array(), NULL, $in_footer);
```

Or, using your function call:

```
wp_enqueue_script("myscript" , get_template_directory_uri()."/js/myscript.js", array(), NULL, true );
```

By the way, passing the script itself as a dependency to itself will probably make something blow up.

Note also: if your script depends on jQuery, just pass jQuery as a dependency, instead of enqueueing it separately:

```
wp_enqueue_script("myscript" , get_template_directory_uri()."/js/myscript.js", array( 'jquery' ), NULL, true );
```

Comment: Thanks--didn't actually mean to put myscript as a dependancy of itself--I was just simplifying the longer scripts there and didnt' notice I gave it the same name.

Comment: Related question, if you care to follow up: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82668/how-do-i-enqueueor-delay-loading-of-script-tags-in-individual-page-posts

Comment: Actually--one question. You put the second parameter (`$src`) in there. But what if I already registered the script and don't  want the source again?

Comment: If you already registered the script, then all of the parameters would go in your `wp_register_script()` call, and your `wp_enqueue_script()` call would simply include the script name: `wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript' )`.