# How do I enqueue(or delay loading of) <script> tags in individual page posts?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

My customer has many pages with `<script>` elements including javascript.

```
<script src="myscriptforthispageonly.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to get all scripts to load in the footer using `wp_enqueue_script()`, but I'm not sure how to enqueue a script from within a page.

Again, this is within a Wordpress **page**. Is it possible to enqueue an external script from a **page** or **post**?

If that's not possible, is it possible to delay loading the script until the onload event fires?

Comment: To answer this question, we need to see actual code. It's really not practical to answer in generalities, in this case.

Comment: I am trying to enqueue hundreds of scripts. Which of them would you like to see the source code for?

Comment: We need some sort of code to have any idea of context. Perhaps post the template file, with a representative example of a script call?

Comment: This is from within a **page**. As in a Wordpress **page**. No templates. Imagine you are writing a Wordpress blog post update, you switch to HTML view, and include a script with `<script src="something"></script>`. How do I enqueue that?

Comment: How are you adding script calls in post_content? More importantly: *why*? There's almost certainly a better way to skin that cat...

Comment: I agree it's not the best approach, but the client is using little widgets that use external scripts. Similar to the Facebook "Like" button API, which includes a little script from Facebook. At any rate, I'm not going to convince them to stop doing it. As for the *How*, you just switch to "HTML" mode, and type `<script src="something"></script>`.

Comment: See my edited answer below, regarding script calls in post content.

Answer (score 3):

General answer: you can call `wp_enqueue_script()` directly inline in the template, as of WordPress 3.4 (IIRC).

So, if you have:

```
<script src="myscriptforthispageonly.js"></script>
```

You could replace it with:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'this-page-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myscriptforthispageonly.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true ); ?>
```

### Edit

From this comment:

> This is from within a page. As in a Wordpress page. No templates. Imagine you are writing a Wordpress blog post update, you switch to HTML vie

Your best course of action would be to define a **shortcode** for the user to put into the post content, instead of putting a `<script>` call itself directly in the post content. Then, in your shortcode callback, you can call `wp_enqueue_script()`.